# Laravel resource controller confusing workflows

Tags: laravel, model, controller, resources

I have created multiple Resource controller by using the following command: **php artisan make:model MobelName -a**. There are some model and controller list:

Models list:

```
Iof
CompanyIof
Company
Test
```

Controller list:

```
IofController
CompanyIofController
CompanyController
TestController
```

The problem is **edit()** method only works for **Company** and **Test** model. dosen't works for **Iof** and **CompanyIof** model

Result found:

```
App\Company {#1379 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: "mysql"
  #table: "companies"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "type" => "1"
    "precedence" => 22
    "systemId" => 23
    "shortName" => "shah alasmasdljk"
    "fullName" => "dsdaf"
    "status" => "1"
    "user_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-12-29 13:58:19"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-29 13:58:19"
  ]
  #original: array:10 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "type" => "1"
    "precedence" => 22
    "systemId" => 23
    "shortName" => "shah alasmasdljk"
    "fullName" => "dsdaf"
    "status" => "1"
    "user_id" => 1
    "created_at" => "2020-12-29 13:58:19"
    "updated_at" => "2020-12-29 13:58:19"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

Result not found:

```
App\CompanyIof {#1367 ▼
  #guarded: []
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: false
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: []
  #original: []
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #classCastCache: []
  #dates: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #fillable: []
}
```

Route:

```
Route::resource('/iof','IofController');
Route::resource('/companyiof','CompanyIofController');
Route::resource('/company','CompanyController');
Route::resource('/test','TestController');
```

Route action like so -

```
{{ url('iof/'.$id.'/edit') }}
{{ url('companyiof/'.$id.'/edit') }}
{{ url('company/'.$id.'/edit') }}
{{ url('test/'.$id.'/edit') }}
```

Resource controller **edit()** method:

```
public function edit(Iof $iof)
{
  dd($iof);
}

public function edit(CompanyIof $companyIof)
{
  dd($companyIof);
}

public function edit(Company $company)
{
  dd($company);
}

public function edit(Test $test)
{
  dd($test);
}
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: can you show the controller method signatures for the actions that are returning new instances

Comment: @lagbox thanks, I am following the Laravel resource documents [link](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/controllers#actions-handled-by-resource-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be a character casing mismatch for your `CompanyIof` route model binding.

You've defined your `route resource` using all lowercase, but used camelcase in your function signature. These need to match for route model binding to work correctly.

```
Route::resource('companyiof', CompanyIofController::class);

public function edit(CompanyIof $companyiof)
{
    dd($companyiof);
}
```

**Update**

If you wish to keep the variable names in you functions the same as those automatically generated in your function signatures when using `php artisan make:model CompanyIof -a` then just update your `route`:

```
Route::resource('companyIof', CompanyIofController::class);

public function edit(CompanyIof $companyIof)
{
  dd($companyIof);
}
```

You will need to update your `url` segments though:

```
{{ url('companyIof/'.$id.'/edit') }}
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but the function signature is auto-generated by the laravel artisan command `php artisan make:model modelName -a'. is it my mistake? please suggest me

Comment: The function signature is created by `php artisan make:model ModelName -a` but you created the `route` in the `web.php` file, that is not automatically generated for you. You could uppercase your route if you want to keep `$companyIof` in your function.